# Questions about GSADF and BASDF test's parameters

Tags: time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm in great need for help and I'll greatly appreciate any answer. I'm trying to implement those tests in RStudio, but the program tutorial asks among various things to input parameters such as "r0", "r1" and "r2". What do they correspond to? Is it possible they are just default that I'm not supposed to edit? I'm sending a link to the tutorial just in case: https://rdrr.io/github/itamarcaspi/rtadfr/src/R/rtadfUtils.R

Comment: You're looking at the code of internal functions from an R package. They are undocumented because they are not meant to be called directly by users. You should look at the package's actual documentation for its exported functions (e.g. `?rtadfr::rtadf`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I do that it doesn't show the BSADF function, which is present amongst other functions in the link I've sent, and the same can be said in the other options. Since I'm not very practical with programming, can you tell me how can I see it?

Comment: Looks like that function isn't used by any exported function in the package. That means that it effectively is not part of the package and you should not have any expectation of it doing anything in particular. Reverse engineering undocumented code is also decidedly off-topic for this board. You'll want to contact the package author.